# Formit, passing values in a preHook

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, formit

Is it possible to pass values from a link to a form? I have a page with four different links and they all supposed to redirect to a form. Each on of them should have a different value and based on that show a different(in content) dropdown.? any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested it but you should just be able to put a snippet call in the form where you want the value to be placed that is dynamic to the form. Then in the snippet just use the $_GET variable to grab the values from the url. From there you can do your logic and return the proper content for the form.